# I cant set up React Native , when i try to start a project cmd stalls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, npx

i was starting to configure the development environment for React Native but in the step where you install React Native library the console stops to load and then crashes.

I have to do npx react-native, the option to type Y or N takes too long to appear, but it appears. When I type Y the CMD doesnt do anything like for 1 hour, and then it crashes. (See image)

[CMD Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2yCr.png)

Hope that someone can help me
Thanks

I have tried npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject, and the error still persists, using Git Bash and no luck, have tried doing npm config set regsitry also no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this bug! I had to change my DNS to the google DNS, it seems that was the problem.